# Combining PDF Pages with Form Fields that have the same name

Tags: pdf, forms

First of all,  I have only recently started to dabble with the advanced features of PDF...

**Quick Backstory:**

As part of my job, I spend much of my time pre-filling account paperwork with redundant information.  So, I created PDF Paperwork Packages for each type of account.  I then added form fields so I can more easily fill in the information.

Recently, I learned that I can name these fields, and if I name two or more of them the same, filling one fills all of them. So, I created cover sheets where I put in all of the redundant info once, and my account paperwork packages will auto-fill for me.  YAY!!!

**My Problem:**

Sometimes, I send out two of the same types of account paperwork.  For example,  client is opening two accounts.  lets call them account A and Account B.  A and B are the same types of account, and require the same paperwork package, but each require different info on the forms.

When I send these to the clients, sometimes they combine the PDF packages into one file to make it easier for them to print.  When I get the completed paperwork back, I find that some of the information from account A is now on the paperwork for account B, and vice versa.  This is because the form fields on the two paperwork packages share the same names.  Combining them jumbles the info.

**The ideal solution:**

I know that I can protect these forms and make it so that clients cannot combine the files; however, An ideal solution would ensure that:

1) One could combine PDF pages without altering the form fields that I have prefilled, even if the combined pages share form fields with the same name

3) People can still utilize the empty form fields to complete the areas that I was unable to prefill

I know that is a tall order, and I hope that my description was clear.  Am I out of luck on this one?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities how this situation can be handled.

As I understand, we have a repetition of the same pages, which are made available to he end user, and not a recombination of individual forms.

In this case, you could use Page Templates, where you mark the pages which may occur more than once as a Template. You then spawn these Template pages with the field renaming option switched on. This will add a prefix to the field names on a given spawned page, making them unique. If you have "common" information, you can prefill before spawning, and leave the individual fields blank.

This is therefore the preparation approach.

If you have already filled forms, and want to recombine them (but no longer have the fields editable, you would flatten the documents, and then recombine.

Finally, if you want to do a mass-prefilling, you could use a specially crafted FDF file containing the data, and working with Template pages (this would, however, create individual files, which would not have unique field names).

FWIW, "refrying" (sending a PDF through a PostScript printer driver and recreate the PDF using Distiller) is something you only should do when you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Max.  I will try to educate myself about your spawning technique and see if i can come up with a solution.  Until then, I am just flattening the PDF files and getting rid of the form fields.  This is a fine solution since 95% of the time, they just need to sign the pages anyway.  There are just a few times when sending PDFs with the form fields available is ideal.

Comment: Is there a way to make the form fields only talk with other form fields that exist on the same source PDF?  (I hope that makes sense).  In other words,  even though two form fields share the same name, they won't copy each other unless they share some other identifier unique to the source PDF file?

Comment: For fields, the name is the key. There are properties which are active on the widget level (that's one specific field with the same name; in the fields list in Acrobat you see the widget number as "#2", for example, after the name); other properties are on field level (change it in one widget, it gets changed in the other ones too). value is on field level. All that said, unless you make a distinction with the field name, there is no differentiation possible for field values.

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled onto a good-enough answer.  For now, I am just clicking on "file" then "print" and then selecting "Adobe PDF" from the printer drop-down.

I make sure that "print in grey-scale" is unchecked so that my highlights still show, then click "Print" to save the new file.

This is effectively the same thing as printing the documents and scanning a new PDF in color.  I don't retain the form fields, but at least the recipient can combine pages without altering the data.

This is probably a "duh" answer to most people, but I know little about this stuff so it's a huge win for me :D